# CASE WHEN and DATEADD select a different column

Tags: sql-server, calendar, case-when, dateadd

I'm trying to select some values where if a certain date falls on a day in the weekend, then it selects either one or more days before, and I made that work. Now I want it to select a value in another column, because I want to display the CalendarID from my calendar dimension.

The code I have that works is the following:

```
SELECT 
i.Item
,CASE
    WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 6 THEN DATEADD(day,-1,c.Date) 
    WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 7 THEN DATEADD(day,-2,c.Date) 
    ELSE c.Date END AS TransactionDate

FROM [dbo].[Items] i
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Dim_Calendar] c ON 
c.Date = q.TransactionDate
```

I have tried below code, but then there appears to be an error in my 'equals' signs.

```
SELECT 
i.Item
,CASE c.CalendarID
    WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 6 THEN DATEADD(day,-1,c.Date) 
    WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 7 THEN DATEADD(day,-2,c.Date) 
    ELSE c.Date END AS TransactionDate

FROM [dbo].[Items] i
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Dim_Calendar] c ON 
c.Date = q.TransactionDate
```

As I thought that I would then get the value of the CalendarID on those particular values. Is there a way to do what I'm asking, and could the solution perhaps be to do the CASE WHEN in the left join statement?

Comment: The values returned are after the `THEN`.

Comment: It's hard to determine what you're trying to return. Did you want to return a date value, or the `c.CalendarId` field?

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you want to do.

The aliases you give in your SELECT clause aren't available to the rest of your query.

You can say something like

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.Dim_Calendar c 
           ON c.date = CASE 
                       WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 6 THEN DATEADD(day,-1,c.Date) 
                       WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 7 THEN DATEADD(day,-2,c.Date) 
                       ELSE c.Date END
```

The query planner is smart enough to optimize this correctly, so it's just verbose, not slow.

Or you can nest your queries something like this, to make your aliases visible.

```
SELECT i.Item, i.TransactionDate
  FROM (SELECT 
              i.Item
             ,CASE c.CalendarID
              WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 6 THEN DATEADD(day,-1,c.Date) 
              WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 7 THEN DATEADD(day,-2,c.Date) 
              ELSE c.Date END AS TransactionDate
          FROM [dbo].[Items]
        ) i
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Dim_Calendar] c ON c.Date = i.TransactionDate
```

But **none of this is debugged**. I'm not sure of the `ON` condition in your left join.